# How to assign pointer to 2D array in struct in C?

Tags: c, pointers

I am having a problem with assigning a pointer to a 2d array located in a struct in C. The code runs but I am getting a compilation error and can not understand how to get rid of it.

First, the struct

```
typedef struct{
  double (*cases)[9];
} myStruct;
```

I then declare a struct of type myStryct and an array in my main program and try to set the pointer in my struct to point at this array:

```
 myStruct a;
 double myArray[5][9] = {
   {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8},
   {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8},
   {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8},
   {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8},
   {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8},
 }
 a.cases = &myArray;
```

The program run fines and I can access elements via the pointer but I get a compilation error:
 Warning: assignment from compatible pointer type. What is the problem here?

Comment: Did you post the actual code ? Why is `myArray` missing a type ?

Comment: This may help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15207888/pointer-to-2d-struct-array-c

Comment: Also refer this one - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6770507/assign-to-2d-array-a-2d-array-in-a-struct

Comment: Try removing the ampersand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myStruct a;
double myArray[5][9] = {
   {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8},
   {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8},
   {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8},
   {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8},
   {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8},
};
a.cases = &myArray[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

problem:

```
void allocate(int ** universe,int n) // to assign pointer "a"  a nXn matrix //
{ 
   universe=(int **) calloc(n,sizeof(int *));
   cout<<"work3";
   int l;
   for(l=0;l<n;l++)
   universe[l]=(int *)calloc(n,sizeof(int));
}
```